# bash string format resets in command use

Tags: bash, git, git-clone

I'm trying to automate git cloning for a class and I'm having trouble with formatting the string in bash.

```
#!/bin/sh
students=()
while IFS=,  read -r lastname firstname; do
    #students+="$lastname$firstname"
    student=$lastname$firstname
    echo $student
    echo $lastname
    git clone "...$student/unit02.git" $student
done < studentNames.csv | tr -d '" '
```

The echo will produce the correct format, the names without quotation marks. When cloning, however, both uses of the $student variable returns back to unformatted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

```
while IFS=,  read -r lastname firstname; do
<logic>
done < <( tr -d '" ' < studentNames.csv )
```

When you write `< studentNames.csv | tr -d '" '` you aren't passing a filtered file into the while loop, you're passing an unfiltered file into the while loop and then filtering all the *output*. The echo statements print the right values because they're being filtered on the spot, but the values in the variables aren't correct.

Comment: Hi,
thank you this makes a lot of sense. Do you know why this error happens? I've seen this syntax before in all of the websites I've seen but my bash doesn't seem to like it.


$ ./gitclone.sh
./gitclone.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./gitclone.sh: line 9: `done < <( tr -d '" ' < studentNames.csv )'

Comment: It's a process substitution. Your shebang is #!/bin/sh instead of #!/bin/bash, if you can switch it then it should work. If you have to use /bin/sh then I can edit the answer. See the manual page here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html

Comment: great thank you. I fixed that but running into other issues I can probably figure out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AaronLimbat: side note: /bin/sh *is not* bash (well, on some systems it is, but on your system it isn't). Also (probably not important here) note that "Git bash" has nothing to do with Git, it's just a port of Bash for Windows systems.